# How can I diagnose Windows access/permission error

Tags: windows, permissions, registry, dns, profile

The title says it. I'm looking for a way to determine exactly which file/registry key this executable is attempting to access. I have attempted to use Windows [auditing capabilities](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315416) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine where the failure is happening but, this failure does not produce audit failure events or show as access denial in Process Monitor.

Of course, If someone has experienced this and can provide a solution to resolve the error directly that would be almost as nice.

Background:

I am using moveuser.exe which is part of the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) to convert the security of local user profiles on a number Windows XP workstations.

Symptom:

Occasionally, moveuser.exe will fail to convert the security of a profile with the error "Error: 5 access denied". I have not been able to determine any commonality among the failing accounts or the computers they reside upon. A given computer may have host 6 profiles, 5 of which convert without issue and 1 which produces the error.

There are a few factors that I'm as sure as I can be about:

-The account I'm using to run moveuser.exe with has full Administrator rights to the local machine and the domain to which the profile security is being converted.

-The failure is not related to file permissions within the profile directory (the entire directory can be moved, renamed, deleted, or successfully converted via a workaround).

I've developed a reliable workaround for these cases but, it is fairly involved and I would much rather understand the root cause of this error and correct it pre-emptively.

My workaround (glad to share it, left out for brevity) seems to indicate that the failure is related to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ ProfileList registry keys but, I cannot determine exactly how/why.

Comment: On which exact version of Windows are you trying to run moveuser.exe?
Also I guess, all of those 6 host profiles are local profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two days after posting this I got to the bottom of the problem. It turned out, just as Rob Haupt suggested to be related to a stuck user hive. The program I was running, moveuser, was reading the Refcount key found under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\ Windows NT\ CurrentVersion\ ProfileList\ <SID>\` and ending immediately.

Setting Refcount to 0 solved the problem immediately

Pushing out [UPHClean](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=1B286E6D-8912-4E18-B570-42470E2F3582&displaylang=en) to all the target machines pre-emptively has all but elimated the problem and we were able to successfully convert profiles on several hundred machines over the last week.

An important note about UPHClean:

I'd tried installing it previously but, it didn't appear to help.  I was too impatient, the [UPHClean ReadMe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/8/7/a87b3d05-cd04-4743-a23b-b16645e075ac/readme.txt) revealed that the service just takes time to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the "regini" command line tool to grab registry permissions for the administrator account?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileMon and RegMon (now Microsoft, formerly SysInternals, still free) to monitor what exactly is being accessed, how, and what rights/access are being requested.

I don't have a URL handy, but a Google search should be able to hook you up with these tools.

Comment: He says he used Process Monitor, which is Filemon+Regmon+more

Answer (score 0):

A couple items I would try.  First, could it be that the user was logged in and the computer hasn't been rebooted.  Microsoft has a product called [UPHClent](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=1B286E6D-8912-4E18-B570-42470E2F3582&displaylang=en) which helps in unloading unneeded user hives.

Next thing I wanted to know, is if you try rebooting before running the moveuser executable.  This [Conversation](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/windowsservermigration/Oct2005/post24224418.asp) seems to indicate this would help with this kind of error.